# I have a simple VisualForce email template that gives a <p> tag error message when I add in the Apex repeat tag.

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template, related-list

**The Template below validates ok, but when I add the repeat tag it get an error:**

When I add the Apex tag here is the message I get: 
Error   Error: Volunteer_Reminder_of_All_Opps line 21, column 7: The element type "p" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "

" 
Error   Error: The element type "p" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".*
[image: Valid VF Email Template]
**This is the updated code  that gives me the error:  block**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a ) instead of a } after recipient Name

```
Dear {!recipient.Name}
```

Comment: Am wondering why its throwing error in line 21 instead of line 12.

Comment: Just because of the order and way the parser is working. VF compiling can be a pain sometimes as the line it shows may have nothing to do with it or it just does not show any line number at all. It is especially quirky when you mix html tags and vf tags like you (and everyone else) has

Comment: @Craig - Did this resolve your issue?

Comment: Thank you!   I needed a second pair of eyes.  So appreciate your time.